# Why is Eclipse not showing me my sub folders?

Tags: eclipse

It was showing me subfolders yesterday but now it's not. I just imported a project into Eclipse.

[image]

If I look at "main" and "test" in the windows file explorer. I can clearly see that they contain subfolders

I tried closing it and starting it again but that didn't work

Comment: Did you try to refresh the folders in Eclipse? Select the folder, then *File > Refresh*.

Comment: Because these subfolders are probably source folders that are displayed collapsed as subfolders of the project folder two level higher (because source folders are more frequently used).

Comment: @howlger has a good suggestion. If `main` and `test` are set to be source folders in Eclipse their contents are hidden, but instead showed at the top-level in the project, with a little "package" icon overlay.

Comment: So what should I do? remove main and test as source folders?

Comment: @klippy You can try to remove then and add them again to see what happens!

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that `main` and `test` are configured to be source folders in Eclipse. Source folder don't show up in their normal file system location, but instead at the top level of the project.

[image]

I guess yours don't because you don't seem to see them.

It's hard to figure out why these folders don't show up. Here is some things to try:

- Verify that you are using the *Package Explorer* view, not *Navigator* or *Project Explorer*.
- Go to the *Filters* configuration dialog in *Package Explorer* (see image below) and uncheck all filters.

[image]